# WHICH PLAYER TAKES THE HAND?

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, strategy, hand

If one player is holding a jack and a three and the other player is holding a jack and an ace and the cards on the table are showing a jack, a three, two 7's and a ten. The first player then has a pair of jacks, a pair of three's and a pair of 7's on the table.  The second player has a pair of jacks, and the same two 7's on the table, with an ace high. They both have a pair of jacks and a pair of 7's but the first player also has a pair of three's, which should trump the ace high. Who has the winning hand?

Answer (score 1):

Every combination is maximum 5 cards. You cant have 3 pairs. Here the player with the highest kicker wins. The highest kicker is the ace.

JJ77A vs JJ773

Ace wins